# COLUMNS_UPDATED() return different values when ColumnId is the same

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I read the article about [COLUMNS_UPDATED()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) on msdn.

There are example. 
I reduce code from example.
Create table with trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employeeData (
   emp_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   emp_bankAccountNumber char (10) NOT NULL,
   emp_salary int NOT NULL,
   emp_SSN char (11) NOT NULL,
   emp_lname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
   emp_fname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
   emp_manager int NOT NULL
   );
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updEmployeeData 
ON dbo.employeeData 
AFTER UPDATE AS
    print COLUMNS_UPDATED() 
    print COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 14
GO
INSERT INTO employeeData
VALUES ( 101, 'USA-987-01', 23000, 'R-M53550M', N'Mendel', N'Roland', 32);
GO
```

1. First update

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.employeeData
   SET emp_salary = 51000
   WHERE emp_id = 101;
   ```

   Trigger returned 0x04 and 4 - **everything OK**
2. Second update

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.employeeData
   SET emp_bankAccountNumber = '133146A0', emp_SSN = 'R-M53550M'
   WHERE emp_id = 101;
   ```

   Trigger returned 0x0A and 10 - **everything OK**

### **But lets try to add some columns**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employeeData2 (
    emp_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_bankAccountNumber char (10) NOT NULL,
    emp_salary int NOT NULL,
    emp_SSN char (11) NOT NULL,
    emp_lname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
    emp_fname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
    emp_manager int NOT NULL,
    trash1 int NULL,
    trash2 int NULL,
    trash3 int NULL,
    trash4 int NULL,
    trash5 int NULL,
    trash6 int NULL,
    trash7 int NULL,
    trash8 int NULL,
    trash9 int NULL,
    trash10 int NULL,
    trash11 int NULL,
    trash12 int NULL,
    trash13 int NULL,
    trash14 int NULL,
    trash15 int NULL,
    trash16 int NULL,
    trash17 int NULL,
    trash18 int NULL,
    trash19 int NULL,
    trash20 int NULL,
    trash21 int NULL,
    trash22 int NULL,
    trash23 int NULL,
    trash24 int NULL,
    trash25 int NULL,
    trash26 int NULL,
    trash27 int NULL,
    trash28 int NULL,
    trash29 int NULL,
    trash30 int NULL,
    trash31 int NULL
   );
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updEmployeeData2
ON dbo.employeeData2
AFTER UPDATE AS
   print COLUMNS_UPDATED() 
   print COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 14
GO
INSERT INTO employeeData2
(emp_id,emp_bankAccountNumber,emp_salary,emp_SSN,emp_lname,emp_fname,emp_manager)
VALUES ( 101, 'USA-987-01', 23000, 'R-M53550M', N'Mendel', N'Roland', 32);
GO
```

Now it return false when update

```
UPDATE dbo.employeeData2
SET emp_salary = 51000
WHERE emp_id = 101;
-- return 0x0400000000
-- return 0

UPDATE dbo.employeeData2
SET emp_bankAccountNumber = '133146A0', emp_SSN = 'R-M53550M'
WHERE emp_id = 101;
-- return 0x0A00000000
-- return 0
```

***Question:
Why 0x04 became 0x0400000000 and 0x0A became 0x0A00000000 ?
ColumnId are the same in both tables.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, msdn is not really clear on this one, but there's a statement, in the doc you're linking to, where you can see that you have to work another way when you have more than 8 columns in your table.

The fact is that you need to use substring when you have more than 8 column, **even if you're working only on the first 8 columns** !

as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/232195), also (the sample code given is the same as in msdn)

> However, if there are more than eight columns, the COLUMNS_UPDATED()
>   function returns the bytes in order from left to right, with the least
>   significant byte being the leftmost. The leftmost byte will contain
>   information about columns 1 through 8, the second byte will contain
>   information about columns 9 through 16, and so on. If there were nine
>   columns in the table and you want to check if columns 2, 3, or 4 have
>   been updated, the correct bitmask to use is 0x0E00 (decimal 3584).
>
> Since the bitwise operator only works on 32-bit integers, you may have
>   difficulty checking a table with more than 32 columns. The correct
>   bitmask to check if columns 3, 5, and 9 have changed when there are 16
>   columns or less is 0x1401 (decimal 5121). The correct bitmask is
>   0x140100 if there are 24 columns or less, 0x14010000 if 32 columns or
>   less, and so on.
>
> Therefore, if there are more than eight columns, you will need to use
>   SUBSTRING to extract the bytes separately